# File with important path definition in PHP

Tags: php, css, path

I'm trying to create file `configuration.php` with all path's defiitions.

First, there is the `autoload.php` file included in `index.php` just after page and session is started.

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'configuration.php';

Const. **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** is default **"/"** but I tried set **DS** manualy as **"/"** too.

Then, in `configuration.php`:

```
define('DS',                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('DIR_BASE',          $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('DIR_CONFIG',        $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
define('DIR_APP',           DIR_BASE.DS.'app');
define('DIR_ASSETS',        DIR_BASE.DS.'assets');
define('DIR_CSS',           DIR_ASSETS.DS.'css');
```

But path generated this way looks following:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/xampp/htdocs/pro_name\assets\css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/xampp/htdocs/pro_name\assets\css/vendor/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/xampp/htdocs/pro_name\assets\css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/xampp/htdocs/pro_name\assets\css/debug.css">
```

and in Chrome Developer Tool I get for example:

`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/pro_name/assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css`

I want to create universal paths for localhost and production server. Where I made mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't specify this, but I suspect the actual problem is that the production system runs on `website.com/index.php` and the development system is using `localhost/w8/index.php`. This extra folder on the dev system causes the issue when the autoloader is set to use `/` as the project root.

The issue with the chrome dev tools is caused by using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which returns the filesystem path instead of the relative website folder path.

To solve this, you need to replicate the production system on your localhost. You can do this by setting a `hosts` entry to something like `project.local` and setting up apache to serve the `htdocs/w8/` folder when accessing this domain.

Use [this guide](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/) to modify your `hosts` file to have the following entry:

```
127.0.0.1 project.local
```

Then, add an entry to your apache config to allow requests to the `project.local` domain:

```
<VirtualHost project.local:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/w8/"
    ServerName project.local
</VirtualHost>
```

**NOTE: This apache config is untested!** Your best bet is to copy the existing virtualhost, change `*` to `project.local`, and to modify the document root to be the `w8` folder instead of the entire `htdocs` folder.

Now, you should be able to access your project by opening `http://project.local` in your browser. You can then set `/` as your `DIR_BASE` and it should work on both your production server and your test system *(as long as you use the alias domain `http://project.local` when working locally).*

I haven't actually tested this, but these are the steps you need to follow to get it working.

Comment: I did it in the past but documentRoot was "C:/xampp/htdocs/pro_name" (without "/" at the end). Problem is path generated this way: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/xampp/htdocs/pro_name\assets\css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: That path should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css">`. If you're using a custom domain to work locally, then you can replace the call to `dir base` with simply `/`